# Replace for loop with .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace the for loop with .each function?

```
    function addOptionsToSelect(placeElement, placeData){
      placeData.sort(comparePlaces);
      placeElement.empty();
      for(var i = 0; i < placeData.length; i++ ){
          var place = placeData[i];
          var option = $("<option>"+ place.name +"</option>").attr("value", place.code)
          placeElement.append(option);
      }
  }
```

Comment: RTM ... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: "Always read the plaque" - or documentation in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can trivially be determined by referring to the readily-available documentation for the function in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one's actually posted it and people seem determined to answer this question, so for completeness, here's a version using [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each):

```
function addOptionsToSelect(placeElement, placeData) {
    placeData.sort(comparePlaces);
    placeElement.empty();
    jQuery.each(placeData, function(_, place) { // Or $.each if $ == jQuery
        var option = $("<option>" + place.name + "</option>").attr("value", place.code)
        placeElement.append(option);
    });
}
```

Note that the first argument is the *index* of the entry; the entry itself is the second argument (and also `this`). Hence `function(_, place)` where we don't end up using the `_` argument (`_` is a valid identifier in JavaScript).

But I would use `Array#forEach` (shimmed if necessary) instead [as Nina suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682504/157247) or any of [the many other ways to loop through arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), a native ES5 method, for it.

> The **`forEach()`** method executes a provided function once per array element.

```
function addOptionsToSelect(placeElement, placeData){
    placeData.sort(comparePlaces);
    placeElement.empty();
    placeData.forEach(function (place) {
        var option = $("<option>"+ place.name +"</option>").attr("value", place.code);
        placeElement.append(option);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM manipulation is costly.So create the entire set of options and add at once

```
 function addOptionsToSelect(placeElement, placeData){
      placeData.sort(comparePlaces);
      placeElement.empty();
     var option ="";
     placeData.forEach(function(item){
     option+ = $("<option>"+ item.name +"</option>").attr("value", item.code)
      })
     placeElement.append(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple **foreach** syntax should do the job.
The Javascript syntax uses a simple "**for**" inlcluding your objects keys:

```
function addOptionsToSelect(placeElement, placeData){
  placeData.sort(comparePlaces);
  placeElement.empty();

  for(var key in placeData)
  {
      place = placeData[key]
      var option = $("<option>"+ place.name +"</option>").attr("value", place.code)
      placeElement.append(option);
  }
}
```

Comment: In fact it's automatic, the "key" argument is deduced by the for statement so the key variable is generated from the object property. No check is required